# Change background & color ontouchmove

Tags: javascript, touch

I have a wordBox Where user will drag touch and drag to select words.

[image: WordBox]

I am using `touchmove` eventlistener to change background/color of the word in wordBox. But `touchmove` only changing color/background of the text from where it started.

```js
    var COLUMNS = 20;
    var ROWS = 12;
    var word = ['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O'];

    var wordLength = word.length;

    

    var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
    

    function select(evt) {
      var id = this.id;
      document.getElementById(this.id).style.background = "#ffffff";
      document.getElementById(this.id).style.color = "#0070C4";

      for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
        mouseMove = spans[i].addEventListener("touchmove", function(sp) {

          document.getElementById(sp.toElement.id).style.background = "#ffffff";
          document.getElementById(sp.toElement.id).style.color = "#0070C4";

        });
      }
    }



    function start() {
      //GENERATE RANDOM WORDBOX
      for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
        spans[i].innerHTML = word[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordLength)];
        spans[i].addEventListener("touchmove", select);
      }
    }

start();
```

```css
html {
  background: #0070C4;
  color: #fff;
}
span {
  padding: 8px 6px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wordBox">
  <div class="column1">
    <span id='r1'></span>
    <span id='r2'>></span>
    <span id='r3'>></span>
    <span id='r4'>></span>
    <span id='r5'>></span>
    <span id='r6'>></span>
    <span id='r7'>></span>
    <span id='r8'>></span>
    <span id='r9'>></span>
    <span id='r10'>></span>
    <span id='r11'>></span>
    <span id='r12'>></span>
    <span id='r13'>></span>
    <span id='r14'>></span>
    <span id='r15'>></span>
    <span id='r16'>></span>
    <span id='r17'>></span>
    <span id='r18'>></span>
    <span id='r19'>></span>
    <span id='r20'>></span>
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    <span id='r21'>></span>
    <span id='r22'>></span>
    <span id='r23'>></span>
    <span id='r24'>></span>
    <span id='r25'>></span>
    <span id='r26'>></span>
    <span id='r27'>></span>
    <span id='r28'>></span>
    <span id='r29'>></span>
    <span id='r30'>></span>
    <span id='r31'>></span>
    <span id='r32'>></span>
    <span id='r33'>></span>
    <span id='r34'>></span>
    <span id='r35'>></span>
    <span id='r36'>></span>
    <span id='r37'>></span>
    <span id='r38'>></span>
    <span id='r39'>></span>
    <span id='r40'>></span>
  </div>
  <div class="column3">
    <span id='r41'>></span>
    <span id='r42'>></span>
    <span id='r43'>></span>
    <span id='r44'>></span>
    <span id='r45'>></span>
    <span id='r46'>></span>
    <span id='r47'>></span>
    <span id='r48'>></span>
    <span id='r49'>></span>
    <span id='r50'>></span>
    <span id='r51'>></span>
    <span id='r52'>></span>
    <span id='r53'>></span>
    <span id='r54'>></span>
    <span id='r55'>></span>
    <span id='r56'>></span>
    <span id='r57'>></span>
    <span id='r58'>></span>
    <span id='r59'>></span>
    <span id='r60'>></span>
  </div>
  <div class="column4">
    <span id='r61'>></span>
    <span id='r62'>></span>
    <span id='r63'>></span>
    <span id='r64'>></span>
    <span id='r65'>></span>
    <span id='r66'>></span>
    <span id='r67'>></span>
    <span id='r68'>></span>
    <span id='r69'>></span>
    <span id='r70'>></span>
    <span id='r71'>></span>
    <span id='r72'>></span>
    <span id='r73'>></span>
    <span id='r74'>></span>
    <span id='r75'>></span>
    <span id='r76'>></span>
    <span id='r77'>></span>
    <span id='r78'>></span>
    <span id='r79'>></span>
    <span id='r80'>></span>
  </div>
  <div class="column5">
    <span id='r81'>></span>
    <span id='r82'>></span>
    <span id='r83'></span>
    <span id='r84'>></span>
    <span id='r85'>></span>
    <span id='r86'>></span>
    <span id='r87'>></span>
    <span id='r88'>></span>
    <span id='r89'>></span>
    <span id='r90'>></span>
    <span id='r91'>></span>
    <span id='r92'>></span>
    <span id='r93'>></span>
    <span id='r94'>></span>
    <span id='r95'>></span>
    <span id='r96'>></span>
    <span id='r97'>></span>
    <span id='r98'>></span>
    <span id='r99'>></span>
    <span id='r100'>></span>
  </div>
  <div class="column6">
    <span id='r101'>></span>
    <span id='r102'>></span>
    <span id='r103'>></span>
    <span id='r104'>></span>
    <span id='r105'>></span>
    <span id='r106'>></span>
    <span id='r107'>></span>
    <span id='r108'>></span>
    <span id='r109'>></span>
    <span id='r110'>></span>
    <span id='r111'>></span>
    <span id='r112'>></span>
    <span id='r113'>></span>
    <span id='r114'>></span>
    <span id='r115'>></span>
    <span id='r116'>></span>
    <span id='r117'>></span>
    <span id='r118'>></span>
    <span id='r119'>></span>
    <span id='r200'>></span>
  </div>
  <div class="column7">
    <span id='r201'>></span>
    <span id='r202'>></span>
    <span id='r203'>></span>
    <span id='r204'>></span>
    <span id='r205'>></span>
    <span id='r206'>></span>
    <span id='r207'>></span>
    <span id='r208'>></span>
    <span id='r209'>></span>
    <span id='r210'>></span>
    <span id='r211'>></span>
    <span id='r212'>></span>
    <span id='r213'>></span>
    <span id='r214'>></span>
    <span id='r215'>></span>
    <span id='r216'>></span>
    <span id='r217'>></span>
    <span id='r218'>></span>
    <span id='r219'>></span>
    <span id='r220'>></span>
  </div>
  <div class="column8">
    <span id='r221'>></span>
    <span id='r222'>></span>
    <span id='r223'>></span>
    <span id='r224'>></span>
    <span id='r225'>></span>
    <span id='r226'>></span>
    <span id='r227'>></span>
    <span id='r228'>></span>
    <span id='r229'>></span>
    <span id='r230'>></span>
    <span id='r231'>></span>
    <span id='r232'>></span>
    <span id='r233'>></span>
    <span id='r234'>></span>
    <span id='r235'>></span>
    <span id='r236'>></span>
    <span id='r237'>></span>
    <span id='r238'>></span>
    <span id='r239'>></span>
    <span id='r240'>></span>
  </div>
  <div class="column9">
    <span id='r241'>></span>
    <span id='r242'>></span>
    <span id='r243'>></span>
    <span id='r244'>></span>
    <span id='r245'>></span>
    <span id='r246'>></span>
    <span id='r247'>></span>
    <span id='r248'>></span>
    <span id='r249'>></span>
    <span id='r250'>></span>
    <span id='r251'>></span>
    <span id='r252'>></span>
    <span id='r253'>></span>
    <span id='r254'>></span>
    <span id='r255'>></span>
    <span id='r256'>></span>
    <span id='r257'>></span>
    <span id='r258'>></span>
    <span id='r259'>></span>
    <span id='r260'>></span>
  </div>
  <div class="column10">
    <span id='r261'>></span>
    <span id='r262'>></span>
    <span id='r263'>></span>
    <span id='r264'>></span>
    <span id='r265'>></span>
    <span id='r266'>></span>
    <span id='r267'>></span>
    <span id='r268'>></span>
    <span id='r269'>></span>
    <span id='r270'>></span>
    <span id='r271'>></span>
    <span id='r272'>></span>
    <span id='r273'>></span>
    <span id='r274'>></span>
    <span id='r275'>></span>
    <span id='r276'>></span>
    <span id='r277'>></span>
    <span id='r278'>></span>
    <span id='r279'>></span>
    <span id='r300'>></span>
  </div>
  <div class="column11">
    <span id='r301'>></span>
    <span id='r302'>></span>
    <span id='r303'>></span>
    <span id='r304'>></span>
    <span id='r305'>></span>
    <span id='r306'>></span>
    <span id='r307'>></span>
    <span id='r308'>></span>
    <span id='r309'>></span>
    <span id='r310'>></span>
    <span id='r311'>></span>
    <span id='r312'>></span>
    <span id='r313'>></span>
    <span id='r314'>></span>
    <span id='r315'>></span>
    <span id='r316'>></span>
    <span id='r317'>></span>
    <span id='r318'>></span>
    <span id='r319'>></span>
    <span id='r320'>></span>
  </div>
  <div class="column12">
    <span id='r321'>></span>
    <span id='r322'>></span>
    <span id='r323'>></span>
    <span id='r324'>></span>
    <span id='r325'>></span>
    <span id='r326'>></span>
    <span id='r327'>></span>
    <span id='r328'>></span>
    <span id='r329'>></span>
    <span id='r330'>></span>
    <span id='r331'>></span>
    <span id='r332'>></span>
    <span id='r333'>></span>
    <span id='r334'>></span>
    <span id='r335'>></span>
    <span id='r336'>></span>
    <span id='r337'>></span>
    <span id='r338'>></span>
    <span id='r339'>></span>
    <span id='r340'>></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ogdubou2/)

I also tried mouse events but getting desired results. How can i achieve this?

Comment: Do share a demo of fiddle ? What do one do with the image ?

Comment: @Rayon Update question with Code

Comment: @Rayon There are no errors. Everything is working fine i am looking a way to change background & colors of span as user drag its finger on span tags(Characters)

Comment: @Rayon mybad i was experimenting with all touch events. In start function it was supposed to `touchstart` and in select function its `touchmove`. I don't see any errors in console.

Comment: You want to select many span elements ? Like drag ?

Comment: @Rayon Yeap.... I also tried with mouseevents but didn't get desired results.

Comment: @Rayon Working fine with desktop. Tried same thing with touch screen not working with touch events. Changes single span only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use [**`Document.elementFromPoint()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/elementFromPoint) with `clientX` and `clientY` to select the current `element`

*The `elementFromPoint()` method of the Document interface returns the topmost element at the specified coordinates.*

```js
var COLUMNS = 20;
var ROWS = 12;
var word = ['H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O'];
var wordLength = word.length;
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
var started = false;

function clearAll() {
  started = true;
  for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].style.background = "";
    spans[i].style.color = "";
  }
}

function select(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (started) {
    var changedTouch = e.changedTouches[0];
    var elem = document.elementFromPoint(changedTouch.clientX, changedTouch.clientY);
    if (elem.tagName === 'SPAN') { //this condition could also be more accurate based on your specificity of the element
      elem.style.background = "#ffffff";
      elem.style.color = "#0070C4";
    }
  }
}

function mouseMoveHandler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  if (started) {
    this.style.background = "#ffffff";
    this.style.color = "#0070C4";
  }
}

function reset() {
  started = false;
}

function start() {
  for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
    spans[i].innerHTML = word[Math.floor(Math.random() * wordLength)];
    spans[i].addEventListener("touchstart", clearAll);
    spans[i].addEventListener("mousedown", clearAll);
    spans[i].addEventListener("touchmove", select);
    spans[i].addEventListener("mousemove", mouseMoveHandler);
    spans[i].addEventListener("touchend", reset);
    spans[i].addEventListener("mouseup", reset);
  }
}
start();
```

```css
html {
  background: #0070C4;
  color: #fff;
}
span {
  padding: 8px 6px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wordBox">
  <div class="column1">
    <span id='r1'>></span>
    <span id='r2'>></span>
    <span id='r3'>></span>
    <span id='r4'>></span>
    <span id='r5'>></span>
    <span id='r6'>></span>
    <span id='r7'>></span>
    <span id='r8'>></span>
    <span id='r9'>></span>
    <span id='r10'>></span>
    <span id='r11'>></span>
    <span id='r12'>></span>
    <span id='r13'>></span>
    <span id='r14'>></span>
    <span id='r15'>></span>
    <span id='r16'>></span>
    <span id='r17'>></span>
    <span id='r18'>></span>
    <span id='r19'>></span>
    <span id='r20'>></span>
  </div>
  <div class="column2">
    <span id='r21'>></span>
    <span id='r22'>></span>
    <span id='r23'>></span>
    <span id='r24'>></span>
    <span id='r25'>></span>
    <span id='r26'>></span>
    <span id='r27'>></span>
    <span id='r28'>></span>
    <span id='r29'>></span>
    <span id='r30'>></span>
    <span id='r31'>></span>
    <span id='r32'>></span>
    <span id='r33'>></span>
    <span id='r34'>></span>
    <span id='r35'>></span>
    <span id='r36'>></span>
    <span id='r37'>></span>
    <span id='r38'>></span>
    <span id='r39'>></span>
    <span id='r40'>></span>
  </div>
  <div class="column3">
    <span id='r41'>></span>
    <span id='r42'>></span>
    <span id='r43'>></span>
    <span id='r44'>></span>
    <span id='r45'>></span>
    <span id='r46'>></span>
    <span id='r47'>></span>
    <span id='r48'>></span>
    <span id='r49'>></span>
    <span id='r50'>></span>
    <span id='r51'>></span>
    <span id='r52'>></span>
    <span id='r53'>></span>
    <span id='r54'>></span>
    <span id='r55'>></span>
    <span id='r56'>></span>
    <span id='r57'>></span>
    <span id='r58'>></span>
    <span id='r59'>></span>
    <span id='r60'>></span>
  </div>
  <div class="column4">
    <span id='r61'>></span>
    <span id='r62'>></span>
    <span id='r63'>></span>
    <span id='r64'>></span>
    <span id='r65'>></span>
    <span id='r66'>></span>
    <span id='r67'>></span>
    <span id='r68'>></span>
    <span id='r69'>></span>
    <span id='r70'>></span>
    <span id='r71'>></span>
    <span id='r72'>></span>
    <span id='r73'>></span>
    <span id='r74'>></span>
    <span id='r75'>></span>
    <span id='r76'>></span>
    <span id='r77'>></span>
    <span id='r78'>></span>
    <span id='r79'>></span>
    <span id='r80'>></span>
  </div>
  <div class="column5">
    <span id='r81'>></span>
    <span id='r82'>></span>
    <span id='r83'></span>
    <span id='r84'>></span>
    <span id='r85'>></span>
    <span id='r86'>></span>
    <span id='r87'>></span>
    <span id='r88'>></span>
    <span id='r89'>></span>
    <span id='r90'>></span>
    <span id='r91'>></span>
    <span id='r92'>></span>
    <span id='r93'>></span>
    <span id='r94'>></span>
    <span id='r95'>></span>
    <span id='r96'>></span>
    <span id='r97'>></span>
    <span id='r98'>></span>
    <span id='r99'>></span>
    <span id='r100'>></span>
  </div>
  <div class="column6">
    <span id='r101'>></span>
    <span id='r102'>></span>
    <span id='r103'>></span>
    <span id='r104'>></span>
    <span id='r105'>></span>
    <span id='r106'>></span>
    <span id='r107'>></span>
    <span id='r108'>></span>
    <span id='r109'>></span>
    <span id='r110'>></span>
    <span id='r111'>></span>
    <span id='r112'>></span>
    <span id='r113'>></span>
    <span id='r114'>></span>
    <span id='r115'>></span>
    <span id='r116'>></span>
    <span id='r117'>></span>
    <span id='r118'>></span>
    <span id='r119'>></span>
    <span id='r200'>></span>
  </div>
  <div class="column7">
    <span id='r201'>></span>
    <span id='r202'>></span>
    <span id='r203'>></span>
    <span id='r204'>></span>
    <span id='r205'>></span>
    <span id='r206'>></span>
    <span id='r207'>></span>
    <span id='r208'>></span>
    <span id='r209'>></span>
    <span id='r210'>></span>
    <span id='r211'>></span>
    <span id='r212'>></span>
    <span id='r213'>></span>
    <span id='r214'>></span>
    <span id='r215'>></span>
    <span id='r216'>></span>
    <span id='r217'>></span>
    <span id='r218'>></span>
    <span id='r219'>></span>
    <span id='r220'>></span>
  </div>
  <div class="column8">
    <span id='r221'>></span>
    <span id='r222'>></span>
    <span id='r223'>></span>
    <span id='r224'>></span>
    <span id='r225'>></span>
    <span id='r226'>></span>
    <span id='r227'>></span>
    <span id='r228'>></span>
    <span id='r229'>></span>
    <span id='r230'>></span>
    <span id='r231'>></span>
    <span id='r232'>></span>
    <span id='r233'>></span>
    <span id='r234'>></span>
    <span id='r235'>></span>
    <span id='r236'>></span>
    <span id='r237'>></span>
    <span id='r238'>></span>
    <span id='r239'>></span>
    <span id='r240'>></span>
  </div>
  <div class="column9">
    <span id='r241'>></span>
    <span id='r242'>></span>
    <span id='r243'>></span>
    <span id='r244'>></span>
    <span id='r245'>></span>
    <span id='r246'>></span>
    <span id='r247'>></span>
    <span id='r248'>></span>
    <span id='r249'>></span>
    <span id='r250'>></span>
    <span id='r251'>></span>
    <span id='r252'>></span>
    <span id='r253'>></span>
    <span id='r254'>></span>
    <span id='r255'>></span>
    <span id='r256'>></span>
    <span id='r257'>></span>
    <span id='r258'>></span>
    <span id='r259'>></span>
    <span id='r260'>></span>
  </div>
  <div class="column10">
    <span id='r261'>></span>
    <span id='r262'>></span>
    <span id='r263'>></span>
    <span id='r264'>></span>
    <span id='r265'>></span>
    <span id='r266'>></span>
    <span id='r267'>></span>
    <span id='r268'>></span>
    <span id='r269'>></span>
    <span id='r270'>></span>
    <span id='r271'>></span>
    <span id='r272'>></span>
    <span id='r273'>></span>
    <span id='r274'>></span>
    <span id='r275'>></span>
    <span id='r276'>></span>
    <span id='r277'>></span>
    <span id='r278'>></span>
    <span id='r279'>></span>
    <span id='r300'>></span>
  </div>
  <div class="column11">
    <span id='r301'>></span>
    <span id='r302'>></span>
    <span id='r303'>></span>
    <span id='r304'>></span>
    <span id='r305'>></span>
    <span id='r306'>></span>
    <span id='r307'>></span>
    <span id='r308'>></span>
    <span id='r309'>></span>
    <span id='r310'>></span>
    <span id='r311'>></span>
    <span id='r312'>></span>
    <span id='r313'>></span>
    <span id='r314'>></span>
    <span id='r315'>></span>
    <span id='r316'>></span>
    <span id='r317'>></span>
    <span id='r318'>></span>
    <span id='r319'>></span>
    <span id='r320'>></span>
  </div>
  <div class="column12">
    <span id='r321'>></span>
    <span id='r322'>></span>
    <span id='r323'>></span>
    <span id='r324'>></span>
    <span id='r325'>></span>
    <span id='r326'>></span>
    <span id='r327'>></span>
    <span id='r328'>></span>
    <span id='r329'>></span>
    <span id='r330'>></span>
    <span id='r331'>></span>
    <span id='r332'>></span>
    <span id='r333'>></span>
    <span id='r334'>></span>
    <span id='r335'>></span>
    <span id='r336'>></span>
    <span id='r337'>></span>
    <span id='r338'>></span>
    <span id='r339'>></span>
    <span id='r340'>></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

### [**Fiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/LuLsLm0e/)

Comment: Sorry Bro... forgot to upvote...You deserve my UPVOTE

Answer (score 0):

A note of caution for clientX / clientY and document.elementFromPoint – clientX is normally the distance to the viewport, excluding the scroll offset. elementFromPoint uses the same position reference. Chrome on Android (version 50.0.2661.89) positions appear to include the scroll offset. The Internet browser on Android and Safari on iOS appear to use the correct reference point. Desktop browsers (Chrome, Firefox, IE9 & up, Edge, and Safari) appear to also use the correct reference point.

If you’re just using clientX and elementFromPoint, there shouldn’t be any issue as the same reference point is being used. I ran into trouble as I was adding the offset back in to position a new element. It worked fine until I zoomed the display on an Android phone and shifted the display towards the left. My new element was positioned correctly on most browsers, but not on Chrome on Android.